# What's the relation between jgrapht-jdk1.5 and jgrapht-core

Tags: jgrapht

I have written a project depended on jgrapht-jdk1.5, but when compile it raise the error "Found duplicate classes/resources in runtime classpath"

Detail log:
16:13:27 [WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.2.0, org.jgrapht:jgrapht-jdk1.5:0.7.3]:
16:13:27 [WARNING]   org.jgrapht.EdgeFactory
16:13:27 [WARNING]   org.jgrapht.Graph

16:13:27 [WARNING] Found duplicate classes/resources in compile classpath.
16:13:27 [WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.2.0, org.jgrapht:jgrapht-jdk1.5:0.7.3]:
16:13:27 [WARNING]   org.jgrapht.EdgeFactory
16:13:27 [WARNING]   org.jgrapht.Graph

16:13:27 [WARNING] Found duplicate classes/resources in runtime classpath.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal. The package org.jgrapht:jgrapht-jdk1.5:0.7.3 is for an old jdk released years ago, whereas org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.2.0 is part of a recent release of jgrapht requiring jdk 1.8

Comment: So I can exclude the dependency of jgrapht-jdk1.5 and only use jgrapht-core?

Comment: Unless you are developing some very old code which needs to run on jdk1.5, there is absolutely no reason why you would want to use jgrapht-jdk1.5:0.7.3
have a look at our user pages on how to use jgrapht: https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki#user-pages